# Search the attribute of an R object

Tags: r, search, attributes

I would like to build a  R object  .rda   or simply a list object to contain several data frames. Then in each data frame I am going to add a small description of the file in the attribute. Now my question is that is it possible to search the particular object to find the data frame which contains a particular string?

For example, I would like to search the string "inflation" to see which data frame has "inflation" attribute in the object.

Comment: Could you give an example of what your data structure looks like? (Creating a simple example called `obj` and then posting the result of `dput(obj)` would be especially useful

Answer (score 2):

@sebastian-c's answer is along the right lines, but it is probably not what you want to do. Here's an example of why:

```
set.seed(123)
data1 <- data.frame(x=rnorm(5), y=rnorm(5))
data2 <- data.frame(x=rnorm(5), y=rnorm(5))
data3 <- data.frame(x=rnorm(5), wowie=rnorm(5))

data1
#             x          y
# 1 -0.56047565  1.7150650
# 2 -0.23017749  0.4609162
# 3  1.55870831 -1.2650612
# 4  0.07050839 -0.6868529
# 5  0.12928774 -0.4456620
A <- attributes(data1) # Let's store these attributes
attributes(data1) <- list(description="The first datum on inflation")
data1
# [[1]]
# [1] -0.56047565 -0.23017749  1.55870831  0.07050839  0.12928774
# 
# [[2]]
# [1]  1.7150650  0.4609162 -1.2650612 -0.6868529 -0.4456620
# 
# attr(,"description")
# [1] "The first datum on inflation"
```

Yikes! We lost all of the original attributes! Thankfully, we can restore them since we had saved them, then try assigning them a different way, using `attr()`.

```
attributes(data1) <- A # Good thing we stored those attributes!
attr(data1, "description") <- "The first datum on inflation"
data1
#             x          y
# 1 -0.56047565  1.7150650
# 2 -0.23017749  0.4609162
# 3  1.55870831 -1.2650612
# 4  0.07050839 -0.6868529
# 5  0.12928774 -0.4456620
attributes(data1)
# $names
# [1] "x" "y"
# 
# $row.names
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
# 
# $class
# [1] "data.frame"
# 
# $description
# [1] "The first datum on inflation"
```

---

> > If you want to take the `attributes(data1)` approach, remember the attributes are a named list, so you can also add an attribute the same way you would add a new item to a list. In other words, this also works: `attributes(data1)$description <- "The first datum on inflation"`

---

That works, so do the same for the other `data.frame`s:

```
attr(data2, "description") <- "The second datum on inflation"
attr(data3, "description") <- "The first datum on deflation"
```

Now, slap together a small function to search *all* the attributes. You can modify the function if you wanted to only search specific attributes.

```
findmyattr <- function(term, datasets) {
    temp <- setNames(lapply(datasets, function(x) unlist(attributes(get(x)))),
                     datasets)
    datasets[as.logical(colSums(sapply(temp, grepl, pattern = term)))]
}
```

Here are some examples of the function in use:

```
findmyattr("inflation", c("data1", "data2", "data3"))
# [1] "data1" "data2"
findmyattr("first", c("data1", "data2", "data3"))
# [1] "data1" "data3"
findmyattr("wowie", c("data1", "data2", "data3"))
# [1] "data3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sebastian, your edited code might have the following problem

```
descriptions <- sapply(lis, function(x) unlist(attributes(get(x))))
```

Here the description includes all the attributes. As a result, the following steps

```
which_descriptions <- grep("inflation", descriptions)
```

produces  larger number other than the exact file number. As a result the following

```
lis[which_descriptions]
```

also does not work.

Comment: This would perhaps be better placed as a comment than an answer, but I've fixed it now. I didn't test the code after I'd made the edits preserving the attributes.